# How to get pictures from every \halign line?

Tags: plain-tex, tex4ht

I'm trying to get separate images from *eqnarray* lines. Problem is that I can't properly insert starting/closing image `\specials` for **tex4ht**.
Lets consider a minimal example (plain tex):

```
\def\startpic{\special{t4ht++math.png}}
\def\stoppic{\special{t4ht+}}

\newif\ifnotfirstcr
\everycr{\ifnotfirstcr\noalign{\stoppic}\fi}

$$\halign{%
  \startpic
  a#&b#&c#\cr
  \global\notfirstcrtrue 
  1&2\cr 1\cr
}$$
\bye
```

I add closing image **tex4ht** tag (`\stoppic`) to `\everycr` (if its not a first `\cr`). 
And starting image **tex4ht** tag (`\startpic`) at the start of `\halign` *line template*.

After compiling TeX and running tex4ht on created .dvi file I get warnings:

```
--- warning --- Improper groups in \special{t4ht+}... idv[1]
--- warning --- Improper groups in \special{t4ht+}... idv[1]
--- warning --- Improper groups in \special{t4ht+}... idv[1]
--- warning --- Improper groups in \special{t4ht+}... idv[2]
--- warning --- Improper groups in \special{t4ht+}... idv[2]
```

Problem is that `special1 14 't4ht++math.png'` and `special1 15 't4ht+'` are not in the same DVI file group level.

```
[
d4 -41497562
d3 1572864
                <------------------ should be here: special1 14 't4ht++math.png'
[
[
special1 14 't4ht++math.png'                    <------- instead of here
fd1 0 11374260171 655360 655360 0 5 '' 'cmr10'
fn0
(a1)
]
[
r3 655362
(b2)
]
]
special1 5 't4ht+'
d3 786432
                <------------------ should be here: special1 14 't4ht++math.png'
[
[
special1 14 't4ht++math.png'                    <------- instead of here
(a1)
]
]
special1 5 't4ht+'
]
```

Maybe I'm adding \stoppic in a wrong place, but I tried `\halign` line template to write like: `\startpic a#&b#&c# \stoppic\cr`, but I get the same warnings.
Maybe anybody could advise how to properly add  `t4ht++` and `t4ht++` specials to DVI
within `\halign`?

Comment: You might want to add the keyword "plain tex", but then \halign is a dead giveaway.

Comment: do you want every table cell as standalone picture, or may whole table be converted into one picture?

Comment: I want every equation of `eqnarray` make as a separate picture. Standard `eqnarray` is made via `\halign`. So answering your question is: I want _every table cell as standalone picture_